# Python3 and pypdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, range, pypdf, xrange

I have a problem with pypdf and python3: when I do `import pypdf` or `import PyPDF2` python shell returns an error "xrange is not define".

I have seen this is a common problem and I tried the suggested workaround

- redefine xrange --> xrange = range
- add try-except
- install pypdf or pypdf2

they does not work.

am I missing something or can anyone suggest me the correct modification?

EDIT - this is the full list of commands I use

[16:45 eugenio@arch-eu ~]

└───> $ pip uninstall pypdf

Found existing installation: pypdf 3.6.0

Uninstalling pypdf-3.6.0:

  Would remove:

    /home/eugenio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf-3.6.0.dist-info/*
/home/eugenio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/*

Proceed (Y/n)?

  Successfully uninstalled pypdf-3.6.0

[16:46 eugenio@arch-eu ~]

└───> $ python -m pip install pypdf --upgrade

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Collecting pypdf

  Using cached pypdf-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (245 kB)

Installing collected packages: pypdf

Successfully installed pypdf-3.6.0

[16:47 eugenio@arch-eu ~]

└───> $ whereis python

python: /usr/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

[16:47 eugenio@arch-eu ~]

└───> $ ll /bin/python

python             python3.10         python3-config     pythontex

python3            python3.10-config  python-config

[16:48 eugenio@arch-eu ~]

└───> $ python

Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 19 2022, 17:35:49) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pypdf

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 1, in 

  File "/home/eugenio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/**init**.py", line 10, in 

    from ._encryption import PasswordType

  File "/home/eugenio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypdf/_encryption.py", line 60, in 

    from Crypto.Cipher import AES, ARC4  # type: ignore[import]

  File "/home/eugenio/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py", line 119, in 

    key_size = xrange(1,256+1)

NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined. Did you mean: 'range'?

>>>

Comment: I had the exact same issue on a mac m1. As you can see in your error log, there's a message about "Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py" which is an issue with the package `pycrypto`. So try to do: `pip uninstall pycrypto`

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2.

Use pypdf. PyPDF2 is deprecated.

You apparently use some very old versions of both libraries. pypdf > 3.0.0 does not use xrange. Try upgrading:

```
pip install pypdf --upgrade
```

pypdf > 3.0.0 only supports Python 3.6+

Comment: Hi, I have the pypdf updated (I ran the command you suggest).
I use archlinux version 6.1.12-arch1-1, python version 3.10.9 and pypdf version 3.6.0

Comment: Great so then the issue must be gone. If you still see an error message with xrange, you still have the old version. You might have installed the new version in another environment

Comment: Sorry, i meant i had already the version updated and i still get the same error

Comment: You are definitely not executing `pypdf==3.6.0`. You might have installed `pypdf==3.6.0`, but the issue very clearly shows that you're not using it. Very likely you are executing a different environment than you're using.

Comment: You can try `python -m pip install pypdf --upgrade`. Using `python -m pip` (or python3; you didn't share how you invoke python) ensures that pip is using the python environment you think it should use.

Comment: I checked again use the python version and the python package listed. when i run  the command you suggest, it returns " requirement already satisfied".
I do the following instruction. run python from shell, digit `import pypdf` it returns the error "name 'xrange' is not defined" as mentioned in the question

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Please share the complete traceback, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: i have previously unistalled pypdf. 
 - python -m pip install pypdf --upgrade
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pypdf
Installing collected packages: pypdf
Successfully installed pypdf-3.6.0
python
Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 19 2022, 17:35:49) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pypdf
<spurios mex>
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined. Did you mean: 'range'?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are trying to import pypdf in Python 3 but it was designed for Python 2, which uses xrange to generate a sequence of integers.Python 3 uses range instead of xrange, which works differently and returns a sequence object instead of a list object.

you can use pypdf2 instead of pypdf which is made for python 3

you can install pypdf2 using the following command:

```
pip install pypdf2
```

or alternatively you can use python 2 to run your code.

Comment: i tried using both pypdf and pypdf2 and they both gave me the same error. In addition,  I have to use python3

Comment: I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. Your answer is wrong. The question asker just needs to upgrade. Pypdf does only support Python 3 by now